# How to set null the error message with Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I'm using this Lib to validate my models, but if a mode is not properly assigned it returns a error message, I just want to retrieve the `StatusCode` but with no message.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty().EmailAddress().WithMessage("");
```

If I put a null or "" in the `.WithMessage` method I get an Exception!

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve the StatusCode"? Are you talking about retrieving the status code of that failed validation or returning a specific HTTP status code from your API to the client without also passing back a list of errors in JSON?

Comment: I just want to validate the fields without returning any error message, only the statuscode. If any of the property is wrong, just return a statuscode and not the error message!

Comment: What do you mean by status code? An http status code signifying validation failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that if you want to return an empty error, then something is wrong with your architecture.

However, you can do it like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty().EmailAddress().WithMessage((_) => "");
```

Such a design can be useful if you don't know in advance what the error message should be. Like this:

```
string error = string.Empty;
RuleFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
    .Must(x =>
    {
        if (someСondition)
        {
            error = "error message 1";
            return false;
        }
        if (anotherСondition)
        {
            error = $"error message 2: {x.ToString()}";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    })
    .WithMessage((_) =>
    {
        return error;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could not set it as null or empty.You would get an error of `A message must be specified when calling WithMessage` if you does not set messages.

> if a mode is not properly assigned it returns a error message, I just want to retrieve the StatusCode but with no message.

The errors do not have an effect when you retrieve the status code.If I use

```
.WithMessage(model => $"");
```

the result is `{"errors":{"EmailAddress":["The input was not valid."]}`

To avoid the exception,a walk around is to use below code(with a space)

```
.WithMessage(" ");
```

and get the result `{"errors":{"EmailAddress":[" "]}`

Comment: There's any way to hide the Property name ?.

Comment: @Nathiel Paulino I do not think you could do that but you could override it using `RuleFor(m => m.Email).NotEmpty().EmailAddress().OverridePropertyName($"")`